# Writing linux conntrack module for DNS requests

Tags: dns, kernel-module, netfilter

I set up a netfilter rule that balances DNS requests using the random mode of the statistics module with some NAT rules. That part worked well however when a DNS client sends all its requests from the same source port the DNS requests all are balanced to the same backend server.

I'm assuming this happens because the connection tracking identifies all the UDP packets as part of the same UDP connection. I couldn't find an easy fix for this, is there one?

In the case there isn't I will have to write some code to make things behave how I'd like. What is the proper approach to doing this?

My first thought was to create something similar to ip_conntrack_ftp that identifies DNS connections by using the ip source/dest as well as the DNS sequence number.

Comment: please identify the _exact_ modules you're using.

Comment: Only the statistics module with a target of DNAT.

Comment: what's the modules full name, i.e. `mod_something.ko` ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need anything that complicated - you just need to find a way to make the load balancer work "per packet" instead of "per flow".

Comment: Yep that would be the easy fix. I couldn't find one.